# What is your opinion about blocking languages based on sy-langu

Tags: localization, internationalization, abap

```
Roses are red,
violets are blue

Unexpected 'Langu'
on line 32.
```

---

Well, to put things short: a technical limitation forced me to ignore Cyrillic material texts (short texts from table MAKT).

As an ABAP guy, I always take the pragmatic solution: I have excluded the languages manually by browsing through table T002 and googling if the languages are based on Cyrillic characters.

It works. But is not sexy. Feedback is appreciated.

```
REPORT Y_TEST_BLOCK_LANGU.

  DATA langu_logon    TYPE c LENGTH 2.
  DATA langu_selected TYPE c LENGTH 1.

  CONSTANTS:
    BEGIN OF language,
      german  TYPE c LENGTH 1 VALUE 'D',
      english TYPE c LENGTH 1 VALUE 'E',
    END OF language.

  CALL FUNCTION 'CONVERSION_EXIT_ISOLA_OUTPUT'
    EXPORTING
      input  = sy-langu
    IMPORTING
      output = langu_logon.

  IF
      langu_logon = 'BG'
  OR  langu_logon = 'KK'
  OR  langu_logon = 'RU'
  OR  langu_logon = 'SR'
  OR  langu_logon = 'SH'
  OR  langu_logon = 'UK'
   .
    langu_selected = language-english.
  ELSE.
    langu_selected = sy-langu.
  ENDIF.

START-OF-SELECTION.

PARAMETERS p_matnr TYPE matnr.

  SELECT SINGLE maktx FROM  makt INTO @DATA(maktx)
       WHERE  matnr  = @p_matnr
       AND    spras  = @langu_selected.

    WRITE: /'This is the text',
           / maktx,
           /'for Material number',
           / p_matnr
           .
```

Comment: Stack Overflow prevents questions seeking recommendations or leading to many opinionated answer. See how to ask [subjective questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). First of all, I really don't understand why you need to avoid cyrillic texts. Testing the logon language looks like a very constraining measure.

Comment: Hi Sandra, thank you for the notice. I will take care next time. The case is still valid because our business warehouse system has some technical limitations to show Cyrillic characters.

Comment: if your application can only deal with Latin text, your solution should exclude all non-Latin characters, including Greek, Arabic and Han characters, so you might need to whitelist what you will accept.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alternatively, you can reverse-exclude starting from the material texts themselves. SELECT all short texts from MAKT that include undesired characters - whatever these are. Then track back which languages these texts belong to. Then put these languages on a deny list. The involved SELECTs may be too time-intensive for online processing, but could be repeated on a regular basis, to fill the DB-persisted deny list.

As some others already noted, the much cleaner solution would be to enable your UI to correctly display those characters. Or, if not possible, you could at least mask them, for example by escaping them to their HTML or UTF codes. This will not look nice, but at least the UI will display something at all.

Also ensure that you investigate other languages, as Dragonthoughts suggests. If your texts include other non-Latin-based languages, you may have the trouble in other places as well. Accidentally hitting Chinese characters may sound a bit off. But think of other widely used characters, such as widely used Greek symbols like alpha, epsilon, omega etc. that might well occur in otherwise English product descriptions.

Comment: Hi Florian, thank you for your input. The reverse-exclude option might be a thing. In case of further topics, as Dragonthoughts indicated, I will implement the idea of yours. As I have investigated the other language-dependent fields, a quick fix was needed. I have added the command SET LOCALE LANGUAGE language-english, in case of my current exceptions list. This action solved all queries for all sy-langu SELECTs.